# ng-hide not working with ng-model

Tags: angular-ngmodel, ng-hide

I want to show/hide div on specific option selection from a dropdown.
But the div stays hidden all the time.

```
 <select class="form-control" ng-model="Type">
                    <option>First</option>
                    <option>Second</option>
                    <option>Third</option>
                    <option>Forth</option>
                </select>

      <div ng-hide="Type==='First'">
      <label>Div Content</div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much better for this purpose ng-switch directive would fit.
Please see [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/FFVuL/1/)

html:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <select ng-model="selection" ng-options="item for item in items"></select>
        <hr/>
        <div class="animate-switch-container" ng-switch on="selection">
            <div ng-switch-when="first">First option</div>
            <div ng-switch-when="second">Second option</div>
            <div ng-switch-when="third">Third option</div>
            <div ng-switch-when="forth">Forth option</div>
            <div ng-switch-default>default</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.items = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'forth'];

});
```

Comment: I have multiple option comparision in ng-switch-when, I dont think its possible using ng-switch.

Comment: Hi in your question was ' want to show/hide div on specific option selection from a dropdown' so what are other multiple option ? Check this out maybe that will help http://jsfiddle.net/FFVuL/2/